# Python/Numba/@jit: Avoiding global variable in a recursive function that uses the return value as a parameter

Tags: python, function, recursion, global, jit

I am currently working on the following code which works running in Python but fails when I try using Numba (@jit) on the function as Numba does not seem to like global variables. I am unsure as to how I should proceed, seen that the global variable r1 needs to be used both for the following loops as well as in the recursion within the loop.The parameters for the function im,c,& r0 are arrays. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
def recloop(im,c,r0):
    global r1
    first=True
    for i in r0:
        if not first:
            temp=r1
        imj1=np.linspace(0,im[1]*(1-i),\
                         np.abs(im[1]*(1-i)-1),dtype=int)
        r1=c[1]*imj1+i
        if len(im[1:])!=1:
            r1=recloop(im[1:],c[1:],r1)
        else:break
        if not first:
            r1=np.concatenate((temp,r1))
        else:
            first=False
    return r1
```

Comment: Provide a bit more background as to what you are trying to achieve. What is the base case of `recloop`. That is what should it return when `len(im[1:]) == 1`. If these are addressed, the function can be written without the need for globals.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @XeroSmith , `recloop` is computing all possible combinations of a sum for a randomly generated array of `c_i` to the integers values of `len(im)` where `im=1/(c_i)+1`. Its a compact way of writing many nested loops. The base case (the first set of tested sums) would here be r0 which is an input, and is calculated `r0=c[0]*imj0`. For the case `len(im[1:])==1`, the last element in the arrays has been reached and there is no more need for recursion and so the `r1` value just above that `if` statement is used. I hope this is clearer, if not, let me know. Thanks!